# Does such a bipartite graph exist?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, co.combinatorics

In the course of my studies on graphs I sometimes use gadgets. I recently came upon a need for a certain bipartite graph with the following properties, and I am wondering if anyone knows if such a graph exists, or can give a construction.

Given two integers $d$ and $k$, I seek an undirected bipartite graph $G=(L∪R,E)$ with:

- All vertices in $L$ have degree either $d$ or $d+1$.
- Exactly $k$ vertices in $R$ have degree $d−1$, all other vertices in $R$ have degree exactly $d$
- The graph is $d−1$ edge-connected.

I really believe that such a graph does exist. But it is a bit difficult to come up with a proof, or a construction. Anyone can show that such a graph exists?

Comment: Do you have any important constraints on $d$ and $k$? An obvious one is that if $d$ is even and $k$ is odd, your graph cannot exist, because it would have an odd number of odd-degree vertices.

Comment: @DavidEppstein The vertices in $L$ can have degree $d$ or $d+1$

Comment: David's question is about $k$. If there is no constraint on $k$ then you can set $k=0$ and  can construct your desired graph. Are you asking whether a graph satisfying your conditions exists for every $d$ and $k$?

Comment: Yes! I want such a graph for every $d$ and $k$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Theorem 1.** *For every $d$ and $k$, there is a graph with the desired properties.*

I'll describe the construction in two stages.

First, construct a bipartite multi-graph $G_1=(L_1, R_1, E_1)$ where

- $L_1=\{\ell_1,\ell_2,\ldots,\ell_k\}$
- $R_1 =  \{r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k\}$
- $E_1$ is the *multi-set* union of $d-1$ matchings $M_1, M_2, \ldots, M_{d-1}$, where
- $M_h = \{(\ell_i, r_j) : (i + j + h) \bmod k = 0\}$ for $h\in\{1,\ldots, d-1\}$

Note that there may be multiple copies of each edge in the multigraph $G_1$.  (In particular, in the case that $d-1\ge k$, we can have $M_h = M_{h+k}$.)  We add a copy of $(\ell_i, r_j)$ to $E_1$ for each occurrence in any matching, making $E_1$ a multiset and $G_1$ a multigraph.

**Lemma 1.** *$G_1$ is $(d-1)$-edge connected.*

*Proof.* Consider the $d-1$ edge sets $M_1 \cup M_2$, $M_2 \cup M_3$, $\ldots$, $M_{d-2} \cup M_{d-1}, M_{d-1} \cup M_1$.  Each such edge set is a hamiltonian cycle, so any cut is crossed by at least $2(d-1)$ edges in the multiset union of these $d-1$ edge sets.  But each edge (copy) occurs twice in this multiset union, so any cut is crossed by at least $(d-1)$ edge (copies). $~~\Box$

Now obtain the desired graph $G=(L, R, E)$ from $G_1$ as follows.
For each vertex $\ell_i$ in $L_1$, replace $\ell_i$ by a distinct copy of $K_{d,d}$ (the complete bipartite graph with $d$ vertices on each side),
and replace each edge copy $(\ell_i, r_j)$ in $E_1$ by an edge from a vertex on the left side of the $K_{d,d}$ to $r_j$, so that each vertex on the left side of each $K_{d, d}$ has at most one edge added in this way.  This is possible because each $\ell_i$ has degree $d-1$, and the $K_{d,d}$ that replaces it has $d$ vertices on its left side.  Note that $G$ is a graph (not a multigraph), and that $G_1$ is obtained by contracting each $K_{d, d}$ into a single vertex.

Take $L$ to contain the vertices on the left sides of the $K_{d, d}$'s (each of degree $d$ or $d+1$).  Take $R$ to contain the $k$ degree-$(d-1)$ vertices in $R_1$, together with all vertices on the right sides of the $K_{d, d}$'s (each of degree $d$).  To finish, we prove the following lemma:

**Lemma 2.** *$G$ is $(d-1)$-edge connected.*

*Proof.* Suppose otherwise for contradiction.  Let $C$ be a cut of $G$ with less than $d-1$ edges.  The cut $C$ respects (doesn't cut) any $K_{d, d}$, because each $K_{d, d}$ is itself $d$-edge connected.  So contracting each $K_{d, d}$ yields a cut in $G_1$ that has less than $d-1$ (multi) edges, contradicting Lemma 1.  $~~~\Box$

Comment: To check my understanding, the resulting graph has $k(d-1)$ many vertices of degree $d+1$?

Comment: Right, because there are $k$ $K_{d'd}$'s, and, in each, $d-1$ of its $d$ "right" vertices get one extra edge from some $\ell_i$.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good construction. It would be great for me if there were only $d-1$ many degree $d+1$ vertices. By any chance can your graph be modified to satisfy this? If it's not straightforward I will think on it more.

Comment: That's not possible in general.  Suppose the left side has $k$ degree-$(d-1)$ vertices and some $i$ degree-$d$ vertices, while the right side has some $x$ degree-$(d+1)$ vertices and some $j$ degree-$d$ vertices.  Then the number of edges must be $k(d-1) + i d = x (d+1) + j d$.  Taking both sides mod $d$ gives $x\equiv -k \pmod d$ as a necessary condition.  So $x=d-1$ is impossible, except maybe in the case that $1 \equiv k\pmod d$ (which doesn't hold in general).

Comment: Hi again. Your construction of $G_1$, a r-regular, r-ege-connected bipartite graph has been really useful to me. I was wondering if the same graph also r-vertex-connected?

Comment: With $r=d-1$?  Not in general.  E.g. take the case when $k=d-1=r$.  Then $G_1$ is just $K_{k,k}$, which can be disconnected by removing the $k$ vertices on one side.  Or when $k=d=r+1$.  Then removing $k-1$ of the vertices on the left leaves just one vertex on the left, which is connected to only $k-1$ of the $k$ vertices on the right.

Comment: Sorry, I want to clarify. You showed that $G_1$ is a graph on $2k$ vertices which is $r$-regular and $r$-edge connected. But I'm asking whether $G_1$ is $r$-vertex connected as well (assuming $k \geq r$). To be $r$-vertex connected, we need to show that the removal of $r-1$ vertices does not disconnect the graph. It seems you are removing $r$ vertices in your examples.

Comment: Good point, I was mistaken (showing they are not $(r+1)$-vertex connected. I'll think about it...

Comment: I think $G_1$ is $r$-vertex connected (if $2\le r \le k$).  Consider deleting any $r-1$ vertices from $G_1$.  Assume WLOG (by symmetry) that $\ell_1$ is deleted and $\ell_2$ is not.  For any non-deleted vertex $\ell_i \ge 2$, let $\ell_{i+x}$ be the next non-deleted vertex on the left.  So (at least) the $x \le r-1$ vertices $\ell_1, \ell_{i+1}, \ell_{i+2}, \ldots, \ell_{i+x-1}$ have been deleted.  Vertices $\ell_i$ and $\ell_{i+x}$ share $r-x$ neighbors $r_{i+x}, r_{i+x+1}, \ldots, r_{i+r-1}$, at least one of which is not deleted, so there is a 2-step path from $\ell_i$ to $\ell_{i+x}\ldots$